# Why fight this character in the North?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In "The Dragon and the Wolf" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E07), Westerosi armies are seen marching towards Winterfell in order to stop the army of the Night King.

But why would they march there in the middle of the winter? It's already been established that regular armies don't fare well in winter conditions while the army of the dead doesn't care about the cold. Couldn't they simply evacuate their population down to the south and deal with the dead around the region of The Neck?

Comment: Except that it's winter *everywhere* now.

Comment: Also, they have (they think) a **wall** to defend...

Comment: @Paulie_D it's always a lot colder in the north

Comment: ...but this is now officially **winter**...a GoT winter....it's gonna be cold everywhere. Regardless, you advance to the enemy and defend you strongholds...that's standard tactics in my limited experience.

Comment: @Paulie_D What do you mean by officially winter? The show hasn't established anything about it currently being officially winter everywhere.

Comment: @Jaood The show does show snow in King's Landing in the Jaime scene in this last episode.

Comment: @Jaood In the last episode of season 6, white ravens were sent out by the masters in the Citadel, as the official notification that Winter had begun.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the Unsullied and Dothraki are *not* `Westerosi armies` - in fact, the Night King's army is more Westerosi than they are.

Comment: Doesn't White Walkers bring winter with them? I thought in ep.1 of season 7 they had blizzard coming with them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There would be nothing "simple" about evacuating the entirety of the North during winter, when the land is even less able to sustain the population. Furthermore, Jon wants to defend the North, not strategically cede it to the Night King.

Even if the entire North could be evacuated, there is no reason to believe that the White Walkers cannot raise *all* corpses, including those that died long ago. This means that their army may grow exponentially as they travel through the North - a place they have not been for many thousands of years.

Comment: A pet peeve of mine: There is nothing exponential about the growth of the army. It might be fast, but not exponential (i.e. growing faster and faster).

Comment: @svick - Its exponential if it uses the enemies it kills to grow, and can kill more the bigger it gets. (In math terms, its growth is proportional to its current size. That's [the definition of exponential growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth)). However, that has nothing to do with the argument in this answer, which is talking about a one-time (huge) boon from taking over existing cemeteries.

Comment: I say exponentially because the population grows as you go further south, and as such, the numbers of available corpses would increase rapidly. For example, White Harbor has the highest population in the North and is the city furthest south.

Comment: it's not exponential, it's linear.  If each corpse you raised allowed you raise more corpses, it'd be exponential. But your "corpse raising" pace is instead controlled by the availability of corpses and the availability of White Walkers.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth

Comment: No, it isn't linear. The number of available corpses increases as they go. There may be a few hundred or thousand near Eastwatch, while there will be hundreds of thousands around White Harbor.

Comment: Exponential doesn't simply mean "a lot". The number of possible corpses is exactly equal to the number of people living in Westeros. The population certainly increases as you go south, but there is no reason to believe the population is an exponential mathematical function of "miles south of the Wall".

Comment: I'm not describing a mathematical function. I'm using the word in the way it is understood in common speech, as the first comment correctly defined - growing faster and faster. That is exactly what I mean. You are all overthinking this.

Comment: The growth of the Wight Army is a piece-wise function defined in different intervals by availability of living people to kill and convert, and fresh and not-so-fresh corpses.  Not a fun thing to write mathematically but I'm sure in certain intervals, it could be described as exponentially growing :)

Answer (score 19):

Because the further south the Night King comes, the bigger his army gets. He raises people he kills, so if they were to wait for him in King's Landing, he'd have millions of soldiers by the time he reached them. He'd kill everyone that he would pass and then raised them to fight in his army. If they want to stand a chance, they need to defeat him asap, as far north as possible.

Comment: To be fair, I'm not sure Cercei "gets" that part. But yeah.

Comment: Based on prior episodes, there are indications the Night King can raise people that have been dead for a considerable time. There's 8,000 years worth of dead and burred people in the North. A significant number of those will still be viable to be animated. Depending on how old a corpse the Night King can raise, that's a few to 100+ times as many people as are currently living in any particular area.

Comment: @Makyen, all the dead Starks (even headless Ned) from under the Winterfell vs the living Starks.

Comment: Fighting against a headless Ned would be super cool!!

Comment: @Makyen we see the Night King animate people but I believe they are always at surface level. Surely anyone dead and buried, even if brought to life, would remain buried.

Comment: @DasBeasto Wights coming from below the surface is [certainly possible](https://youtu.be/pocQRPl1FYQ?t=120). It's probable that the ones in that sequence were already animated, but there's nothing that indicates that being burred blocks the Night King from animating a corpse/skeleton.

Comment: @Makyen I didn't really mean being buried would block his animation powers, but that when the Wight comes to life it would still have X lbs/tons of dirt laying on it. The one in that video seems to be fairly close to the surface but I wonder how long something could be dead before its buried too deep to move from the weight.

Answer (score 2):

I think, as @Paulie_D mentioned in the comments, the main reason is that (as far as anyone knows) they have a giant impregnable wall to the North. This wall gives them a single fortified position where their armies will have strategic high ground. Just like you would defend a castle by getting up on the castle walls and using the ramparts as a defense, the south is their castle and they will use The Wall the same way.